# Не появляются уведомления в Android

Tags: java, android, android-notification

Пробую сделать уведомление в Android Studio. При нажатии на кнопку на панели вверху смартфона должно появиться уведомление. Но ничего не происходит. В логе сначала была запись "SkAndroidCodec::NewFromStream returned null", но потом я поменял картинки в setSmallIcon() и setLargeIcon() (поставил свои картинки png-формата, до этого стояли те, которые изначально были в AS), и больше ничего не появлялось. Что делать? Помогите пожалуйста.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private NotificationManager notificationManager;
private static final int NOTIFY_ID = 101;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext());

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

            builder
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplication().getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                    .setTicker("Новое уведомление")
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentTitle("Уведомление")
                    .setContentText("Тут какой-то важный текст");

            Notification notification = builder.build();
            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы используете AppComactActivity те Activity из SupportLibrary, используйте и `NotificationCompat.Builder`. Согласно документации необходимо использовать каналы `NotificationChannel`  для версий 26+  я немного изменил ваш пример попробуйте.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private NotificationManager notificationManager;
private static final int NOTIFY_ID = 101;
private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "CHANNEL_ID";
private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID)
                            .setAutoCancel(false)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                            .setContentTitle("Title")
                            .setContentText("text")
                            .setPriority(PRIORITY_HIGH);

            createChannelIfNeeded(notificationManager);
            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
        }
    });
}

public static void createChannelIfNeeded(NotificationManager manager) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_ID, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное. Буду работать дальше)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы перехватывать сообщение в фоне, нужно отправлять только data тело, а notification не нужно. сам проверил работает

это для REST:

```
Rootobject msg = new Rootobject()
{
    message = new Message()
    {
        name = "Test",
        data = new Data
        {
            body = message,

       title = title
        },
        topic = "StylePollyNews"
    }
```

Потом все в json.

А это премник:

```
public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
{
    base.OnMessageReceived(message);
    var notification = message.GetNotification();
    if (notification != null)
    {
        var title = notification.Title;
        var body = notification.Body;
        SendNotification(title, body);
    }
    else
    {
        //вот тут как раз и перехват
        var title = message.Data["title"];
        var body = message.Data["body"];
        //Метод с локальным уведомлением
        SendNotification(title, body);
    }
}
```